# How to vectorize an anonymous function in GNU Octave?

Tags: octave

I have to graph the following function in GNU octave within the limits [-3/2, 5/2]:

```
 f(t)= ((t**6) - (4 * (t**4)) - (2 * (t**3)) + (3 * (t**2)) + (2 * t))
```

for a better efficiency i have to first vectorize it . Can I achieve this by just passing the R.H.S as a string to vectorize( ) like written below :

```
fx = vectorize("((t**6) - (4 * (t**4)) - (2 * (t**3)) + (3 * (t**2)) + (2 * t))")
```

An then for plotting the function i can write :

```
fplot(fx, [-3/2, 5/2])
```

Need comments and guidance, if anything can be improved.

Comment: We're not all that good at comments and guidance. For one, how would an accepted answer to that look like? Do you have some specific question?

Comment: "Can I achieve this by [...]". Have you tried it? Just type it in and see what happens! Isn't that easier than asking the question here? Or is your question actually something else?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Create an anonymous function using array operations instead of matrix ones.

```
f = @(t) t.^6 - 4 * t.^4 - 2 * t.^3 + 3 * t.^2 + 2 * t
fplot(f, [-3/2, 5/2])
```

Relevant manual pages:

- https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Function-Handles-Anonymous-Functions-Inline-Functions.html
- https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Basic-Vectorization.html#Basic-Vectorization

Comment: Sir,   for someone who is new to octave , will get confused while writing the anonymous functions. and hence I was looking for a suitable method which can convert any function to vectorized function . Let say , if have to write this anonymous function at first i would have written it like this : f = @(t) t.^6 - 4 .* t.^4 - 2 .* t.^3 + 3 .* t.^2 + 2 .* t . Hope you can see the difference. Kindly guide

Comment: One more point . consider a small portion 4 .* t .^4 can be written as 4 * t .^4 as 4 is a scalar and broadcasting happens in both cases, in matrix multiplication as well as in element wise multiplication  so there is no difference  between 4 .* t  and 4*t , if i have to evaluate f(t) = 4 * t  for a range of values for t

Comment: and hence i can write f = @(t) t.^6 - 4 * t.^4 - 2 * t.^3 + 3 * t.^2 + 2 * t for t in range[-3/2 , 5/2]

Comment: @ManpritSingh yes to all the above. In fact, I typically choose `*` over `.*` in code when scalars are involved, just as a visual hint in the code.

Answer (score 1):

so, as suggested in the comments, I tried out your code.  It seems to do what you're suggesting - it creates a version of the function that is able to be vectorized and plots it.

```
>> fx = vectorize("((t**6) - (4 * (t**4)) - (2 * (t**3)) + (3 * (t**2)) + (2 * t))")

fx = ((t.**6) - (4 .* (t.**4)) - (2 .* (t.**3)) + (3 .* (t.**2)) + (2 .* t))

>> fplot(fx, [-3/2, 5/2])
```

[image: fplot of fx]

So, I guess that's it?  Without knowing what else you're going to want to do, it's hard to make any other suggestions. Note that the `vectorize` function isn't magic.  It just makes sure the arithmetic operators won't accidentally trigger matrix multiplication. see:

```
>> help vectorize

-- vectorize (FUN)
 Create a vectorized version of the inline function FUN by replacing
 all occurrences of '*', '/', etc., with '.*', './', etc.
```

Obviously that's something you could easily do yourself if writing the original function, and is actually very useful to learn so you don't introduce errors in your code.  In fact, some people think it's better to get away from functions written as strings rather than the direct 'anonymous' functions that @Tasos shows in his answer. The `vectorize` function is mainly useful when using a function that may be read in, or obtained/generated in a way that makes the 'vectorize` function useful in an algorithm.  @Tasos 's links above are a very good place to start learning.

Comment: See.... here you got my point ... writing an anonymous function is error prone . instead of writing an error prone code, why not prefer to vectorize it using vectorize( ) . For someone who has just starting to use Octave/Matlab .